# Two printfs print the same string differently

Tags: c, linux, pointers, gcc, i386

I am trying to create a library that handles big integer arithmetic. Big integers are stored in a struct:

```
typedef struct BigInt BigInt;
struct BigInt
{
    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t *data;
};
```

the first member is an uint32_t containing the length of the number and the second member is a pointer pointing to the actual number data (stored in two's complement). I have written a simple toHex(BigInt *a) function that allocates memory, prints the hexadecimal value of the big integer to the string, and returns the address.

In my main loop, I have the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *ap, *bp;
    BigInt *a = fromUInt32(0x7fffffff), *b = fromUInt32(1), *c = fromUInt32(0x80000000);
    _add(a, b);
    ap = toHex(a);
    bp = toHex(c);
    printf("%s\n", ap);
    printf("%s\n%s\n", ap, bp);
    printf("%s\n%s\n", ap, bp);
    free(ap);
    free(bp);
    deleteBigInt(a);
    deleteBigInt(b);
    deleteBigInt(c);
}
```

which, curiously enough, prints

```
0000000080000000
0
0000000080000000
0000000080000000
0000000080000000
```

So the second printf statements print something different for ap than the first and third printf statement. It seems the first printf statement is correct, and the second one is messing up. I have stepped through my code with GDB and after the evaluation of toHex, ap points to the string "0000000080000000", terminated by a null pointer.

I am completely baffled. As far as I can see, the possibilities are:
1. I have run into undefined behaviour for some weird reason.
2. In _add I call a routine written in x86 assembly code, there may be an error in it (but I do adhere to GCC's calling conventions by preserving esi, edi, ebx, ebp, and esp).
3. There is a bug in printf, which seems very unlikely.

Also I have an obvious "memory leak" (quoted because the opinions on what a memory leak exactly is seem to differ) by not freeing the memory allocated by toHex, but this should not matter.

My toHex function was requested by Sourav Ghosh, and is as follows:

```
char numToHex[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
char *toHex(BigInt *a)
{
    char *result, *ptr;
    // allocate enough space for 8 characters for each uint32_t and 1 terminating 0
    ptr = result = malloc(a->size * 8 + 1);
    // loop over the uint32_t's stored in a->data
    // (there are a->size of them)
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < a->size; i++)
        // parse 8 blocks of 4 bits
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            // grab the right bits and convert them to a hex digit
            *(ptr++) = numToHex[(a->data[i] >> ((7 - j) * 4)) & 0xf];
    // add a terminating zero byte
    *ptr = 0;
    return result;
}
```

I have isolated this weird behaviour in a program of [~100 lines of C](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:4dd9) + [~70 lines of assembly](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:4dda). Compiling can be done with

```
nasm -f elf -s <AssemblyName>.asm
gcc <CFile>.c <AssemblyName>.o -o <OutputProgram> -m32 -std=c99 -g
```

The code is uncommented and meant for people who want to inspect the behaviour for themselves.

EDIT: Jan Spurny and Matt McNabb urged me to use Valgrind. Valgrind says: 
Invalid read of size 1 at 0x40A5685: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1655) by 0x40AA7FE: printf (printf.c:34) by 0x4075904: (below main) (libc-start.c:260) Address 0x42121af is 1 bytes before a block of size 17 alloc'd at 0x40299D8: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so) by 0x804887D: toHex (weird.c:107) by 0x8048565: main (weird.c:30)

But this doesn't make sense, as I set result to malloc in toHex, and didn't change anything after that. My bet now is that some register is getting corrupted in the assembly function. Edit2: After checking with GDB, I can see that no registers are corrupted. I am still clueless.

Comment: can you please show us `toHex()`?

Comment: BTW, if anyone wants to see some code that actually compiles I can try to make a little example program.

Comment: The `toHex` function looks fine to me, so I think that your problem will be inside `fromUInt32` function. You should have had posted complete example program in the first place. It's impossible to find this sort of bug without complete source.

Comment: Also you could try running it in valgrind..

Comment: @Jan Spurny: Yes, but I manually checked the result from fromUInt32(). Also, a bug there does not explain why the two printf's print something different for the string ap.

Comment: I would review `_add` too; [Here are the calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions). I suspect you're writing 32-bit x86 code right? Then I'm guessing you're using `cdecl`, in which _all_ arguments go on the stack and only eax, ecx, edx are caller-save; _All other registers_ are _callee-save_. The return value goes into EAX for integers/pointers and ST0 for floating-point numbers

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the `malloc` in `toHex` is somehow the wrong size, so that the `malloc` in the second call (which will be evaluated before the second `printf` is called) stomps on the memory allocated for the first call. The areas allocated by `malloc` tend to be close to one another. I can't see what's wrong in this case, but this might be worth some close examination.

Comment: @NormanGray Good suggestion, but I think that in that case, all printfs would still print the same value.

Comment: Unrelated and off-topic, If your code used `for (uint32_t j = 0; j < 32; j+=4)` instead, you could use `*ptr++ = "0123456789abcdef"[a->data[i]>>j & 0xF];`, a more elegant expression of same.

Comment: @MonKeePoo if you're not allocating enough memory, then anything goes (undefined behavior)

Comment: UB is UB, that if any looks like UB to me. Reason for UB is always the same: violating the C standard.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist that is correct.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen I see (but what exactly causes the undefined behaviour? You would still access memory that is claimed by malloc, so I don't see a reason for undefined behaviour: I will check it out though). Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @MonKeePoo UB in the sense that you'd be using memory that is claimed by some other malloc (including, potentially, a malloc that printf uses).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Ok... That would make sense. I don't have any experience with undefined behaviour. Any tips how I can find out if and where I violate the C standard?

Comment: @MonKeePoo Can you put up the asm code for _add?

Comment: What is `BigInt` and the value of `size` member?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist that's only when it's two leading underscores, or one leading underscore followed by a capital letter. Leading underscore + lowercase letter is perfectly fine.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Ah, that is clear. I was thinking you meant the case where both of the toHex calls were editing each other's memory.

Comment: 1 notable thing is that `0x7FFFFFFF` is maximum value representable by `int32_t` and adding 1 to it ... is UB.

Comment: @MonKeePoo [your comment here assumes incorrectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076516/two-printfs-print-the-same-string-differently?noredirect=1#comment46388162_29076516). There is nothing guaranteed in the execution of your program after you do something that has UB.

Comment: @MonKeePoo actually checking the result from `fromUInt32` does not solve anything. There is probably some bug inside that function which, on its second call inside the `printf` function, writes something somewhere it should not. When that function is called, there is the `ap` value on the stack and it is perfectly capable of messing it up. Again, use valgrind.

Comment: Your code doesn't release the memory allocated with `malloc`. Did you forget it or is this not the real code. Probably the problem is in the code not shown. It would would not harm to have this memory leak since the process terminates after return from `main`. But more interesting is when you release the memory.

Comment: Show us full code. This is going nowhere.

Comment: @JanSpurny I agree. The full code is very long (+-700 lines of C). I just isolated the problem and uploaded it, see the end of the (edited) question. Sadly, the code is still quite long and includes assembly. Maybe I can cut it down to a lot less, but this will cost me some time. Also, I'm looking into valgrind now,

Comment: @harper indeed, I addressed this in my question, but I changed it now to free the memory. This doesn't change anything though.

Comment: The issue may be in your assembly code. Try implementing `addHelper()` in C and see if the program's behaviour changes.

Comment: After stepping through the opcodes with gdb, I discovered that GCC replaces my first printf by a puts.

Comment: @MonKeePoo That's not a bug, though it may arise as a consequence of one. GCC is so smart that if it can statically determine what a `printf`'s arguments are, it will substitute them in; And if all arguments are filled in, then instead of invoking the expensive `printf` with all its parser overhead (which won't be used because all args are filled in), it will instead construct a call to the leaner `puts`.

Comment: The problem indeed seems to be in the assembly routine I've written, though I can't figure out exactly what is wrong. printf gets a certain pointer that seems to be correct (upon inspection in gdb), but Valgrind registers a read at a place that is off by one (That is ap = address returned by malloc, but printf seems to read at a different place). When I try to explicitly print the address of ap that is passed to printf, the bug dissappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made [a thread](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=29146) on forum.osdev.org (there are some really smart people there), and jnc100 notified me that the ABI expects the direction flag to be cleared when functions are called. I set the direction flag in the assembly routine (which is called in _add), and indeed clearing in the assembly routine solves the problem.

Answer (score 6):

The `reduce` function has a bug:

```
while (i < a->size && !(a->data[i])) i++;
if (a->data[i] & SIGNBIT) i--;
```

If the `i < a->size` condition is hit, then `a->data[i]` accesses out of bounds, causing undefined behaviour.  The other branch of `reduce` has the same problem

---

There's a bug in the `_add` function (although this is not triggered in your test case):

```
void *k = realloc(a->data, b->size * 4);
memmove((void *)(a->data + displacement), (void *)a->data, a->size * 4);
// ....other code using `a->data`
```

After `realloc`, `a->data` becomes indeterminate so it causes undefined behaviour to use it.  This could explain your symptoms as a future allocation might re-use the same freed block which `a->data` is still pointing to.

Maybe you meant to also have a line `a->data = k;` after this?

---

To get good help with debugging your code it would be great if you could do the following:

- Check the result of all `*alloc`-family functions and exit if `NULL` is returned.  Otherwise you get undefined behaviour (it's not reliable to expect a segfault).
- Rewrite the assembly function in C. This is a good idea for a number of reasons (debugging, code portability, optimization). It might even turn out that gcc -O3 generates faster code than your handwritten version; that's what compilers are good at.
- Inspect the result of calling `newAddress` to check it actually returns what you expected in your test case.

Comment: This is a bug indeed, but this code is not executed in the program. Commenting the whole if (a->size < b->size) out, and compiling and running the program again still yields the same output. Good spot though, and sorry for the bug.

If my assembly calls realloc, it returns the return value of realloc, else it returns zero. Then in _add I do:
uint32_t *newAddress = addHelper(...); if (newAddress) a->data = newAddress;

and I think this should work. Good point though, I think the error is in the assembly indeed,

Comment: @MonKeePoo updated. There are bugs in `reduce` although IDK if it is called in your test-case. The obvious place that bugs might be is in the assembly code. If you don't want to rewrite it in C then I'd highly recommend trying to debug it yourself: step through in a debugger that shows CPU view and make sure everything is exactly as you expect

Comment: You're obviously concerned about performance so can I suggest redesigning so that the data elements of the BigInt are in little-endian order. Then to "overflow" and "reduce" you just append to the end, or reduce `size` ; you don't need to do a `memmove`.

Comment: Yes, excellent suggestion. I might eventually make a second version of the routines. I'll definitely consider this.

Comment: How about using [__builtin_add_overflow](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html)?  I believe it requires a (very) new build of gcc, but sometimes builtins give better perf than human-written asm.